# How to decouple this transitive dependency

Tags: go, decoupling

I'm trying to figure out how to remove a transitive dependency from my service.

Let's call my service **ServiceA**.

**ServiceA** depends on **LibraryB**. **LibraryB** depends on **LibraryC**. Therefor **ServiceA** transitively depends on **LibraryC**. Let me explain how...

In this case **LibraryC** happens to be the **ozzo-validation** library. In this library there is a type named `Errors` that is defined as a `map[string]error`. You can see it at https://github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation/blob/v3.6.0/error.go but here it is for reference:

```
package validation

type Errors map[string]error

// Implement the error interface
func (es Errors) Error() string {
    // Implementation omitted for brevity
}
```

Note the type `Errors` implements the `error` interface.

As I already wrote **LibraryB** depends on **LibraryC**, ozzo-**validation**. **LibraryB**'s use of **ozzo-validation** is this:

```
package web

// Error responds to a request with an error object and the specified status
func Error(w http.ResponseWriter, err error, status int) {
    // Implementation omitted for brevity
    errors, ok := err.(validation.Errors)
    if ok {
        for key, err1 := range errors {
            // Implementation omitted for brevity
        }
        // Implementation omitted for brevity
    }
    // Implementation omitted for brevity
}
```

That's the entire usage. **LibraryB** imports **ozzo-validation** so that **LibraryB** can do a type assertion, `errors, ok := err.(validation.Errors)`, and then range over the map, `for key, err1 := range errors`.

My service, **ServiceA**, has no idea that **LibraryB** has a dependency on **ozzo-validation**. **ServiceA** also wants to use **ozzo-validation**, but needs to use a newer version because the newer version has more features and some important bug fixes. This newer version is v4.3.0. **ServiceA** calls some methods in **ozzo-library** that return a `validation.Errors` instance and passes that instance to **LibraryB**'s `web.Error` function as the `err error` parameter.

This is where the fun starts. Because **ServiceA** is passing in a v4.3.0 `validation.Errors` instance and **LibraryB** is type asserting against v3.6.0 `validation.Errors` the type assertion fails even though the type definitions are exactly the same in both v3.6.0 and v4.3.0.

How can I fix this problem?

I do have access to **LibraryB**'s source code and I can change it. I could easily upgrade **LibraryB** to use v4.3.0 of **ozzo-validation**, but that would perpetuate this transitive coupling. I'd much rather remove this transitive coupling completely.

I've tried changing the type assertion in **LibraryB** to

```
errors, ok := err.(map[string]error)
```

because ultimately that's exactly what the instance is, `map[string]error` but the compiler doesn't like that because `map[string]error` doesn't implement the `error` interface.

Is there some way I can make my own object that implements `error` and is also range-able so that I could wrap the v4.3.0 `validation.Errors in some kind of interface or something that will break this transitive coupling?

What can I do to break this tight, transitive coupling?

Comment: validation v3 and validation v4 are **different**, unrelated  packages. This might Seen strange but thats how modules work and is the mechanism which allows to use both versions. So validation@v3.Errors is a different type than validation@v4.Errors and of course you cannot type assert different types.

Comment: But: validation@v3.Errors and the v4 version do have the same underlying type and this can be converted _after_ the appropriate type assertion. You **cannot** break this coupling. If ServiceA calls into ServiceB and B requires a validation@v3.Errors than A has to pass a validation@v3.Errors and there is no cheating around this hard dependency.

Comment: ServiceA must import both packages validation/v3 and validation/v4, convert one Errors type to the other and pass the v3 version to ServiceB. Once you understand that different major versions of a package are different packages you‘ll see that the transitive coupling is there and cannot be magically tricked away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If backwards compatibility of LibraryB is a concern, just upgrading ozzo-validation in LibraryB to v4 is not an option. Because if there is a ServiceD that uses LibraryC@v3 and LibraryB, such an upgrade would break ServiceD.

Fortunately, with help of Go Modules, LibraryB can import both v3 and v4 and do type assertions against both versions.

```
package web

import (
 validationv3 "github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation/v3"
 validationv4 "github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation/v4"
)

// Error responds to a request with an error object and the specified status
func Error(w http.ResponseWriter, err error, status int) {
    // Implementation omitted for brevity
    errorsv3, ok := err.(validationv3.Errors)
    if ok {
        for key, err1 := range errorsv3 {
            // Implementation omitted for brevity
        }
        // Implementation omitted for brevity
    }
    // Implementation omitted for brevity


    errorsv4, ok := err.(validationv4.Errors)
    if ok {
        for key, err1 := range errorsv4 {
            // Implementation omitted for brevity
        }
        // Implementation omitted for brevity
    }
    // Implementation omitted for brevity

}
```